# MQTT topic subscription using regex

Tags: c#, mqtt

I am having multiple device specific host applications developed in C# that subscribes to the same Standard MQTT topic.I am using MQTT 5.

For example Host1 app is for Device1 and Host2 app is for Device2.
Both the devices are publishing message on topic: `mytopic/message/{serialNumber}` where `serialNumber`  is dynamic. For device1 it can be `1D12345` and for Device2 `1Y12345`.

Now as both the hosts are subscribed to the same standard topic: `mytopic/message/+` if Device1 publishes message then Host2 is also receiving the message which is not intended.

Is there any way that from application I can subscribe to topic like in Host1 topic: `device/v1/1D*`, if the last slice is starting with `1D` then only it should receive message. I know `1D*, 1D+, 1D#` are not valid in topic but I am looking for any alternate method to solve this. Also the topic is standard so it can not have device type like `mytopic/message/device1/{serialNumber}`

Answer (score 1):

No, subscriptions are handled in the broker, not the client. Topic patterns are defined in the MQTT specification and there are only 2 types of wildcards available.

`+` This matches a single MQTT topic level and can appear at any location in the topic pattern. e.g. `foo/+/bar` will match `foo/one/bar` or `foo/two/bar`

`#` This matches multiple whole MQTT topic levels, but can only be used at the end of the topic pattern. e.g. `foo/#` will match `foo/bar` and `foo/bar/one` and `foo/bar/one/two`

There is no way to use a topic pattern that will match part of a topic level.

The best you can do is to use a topic pattern that matches the all serialnumbers and then apply the regex on the client side to see if the message matches the pattern you want.

If you need to be able to partition by serial number prefix you are going to need to change the topic structure to include the prefix.